# How to mix browser output and low latency DAW audio in Windows

Tags: windows-10

I want to be able to hear on the same soud card output the audio from the browser and the audio from my DAW (Bitwig studio, which has support for ASIO, jack and WSAPI).

I do not care about the latency of the browser audio (as long as I can hear it on the headphone), but I want the DAW to work at very low latency (few ms), which would mean output audio from DAW either to ASIO or Jack (as far as I know).

I tryed to fiddle with Jack, ASIO and even used AB-Audio ASIO bridge, but I do not understand a way of doing what I want. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: So you want to hear audio from video and DAW simultaneously? ASIO drivers are a must for low latency. I'd add extra audio track in the project for the browser audio. Best would be if your interface can create virtual channels where you feed the browser audio, then use those as input for the new track. If not, [VB-Audio's](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm) Virtual Audio Cable, Voicemeeter or Banana should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution for me was to direct the sound from the browser to VB-Audio's Virtual Audio Cable. Then use ASIO4ALL to create audi interface that groups card output and the Virtual Cable input. Then inside the DAW enable pass-thourgh for Vritual Cable output.